# R: how to extract pieces of text from a string based on a pattern

Tags: r, regex, text, nlp

I have a dataset where each row contains a string of text of this type

```
1)list(text = \"incredible hosts\", relevance = 0.87518, count = 1), list(text = \"Japan\", relevance = 0.675236, count = 1), list(text = \"support\", relevance = 0.625663, count = 1), list(text = \"result\", relevance = 0.359757, count = 1)


2)list(text = \"British fleet\", relevance = 0.912888, count = 1), list(text = \"worst maritime disasters\", relevance = 0.904047, count = 1), list(text = \"British history\", relevance = 0.755491, count = 1), list(text = \"Scilly Isles\", relevance = 0.716508, count = 1), list(text = \"sailors\", relevance = 0.691141, count = 1), list(text = \"evening\", relevance = 0.597375, count = 1), list(text = \"Tragedy\", relevance = 0.577141, count = 1), list(text = \"prize\", relevance = 0.565035, count = 1), list(text = \"rocks\", relevance = 0.543257, count = 1), list(text = \"innovation\", relevance = 0.529463, count = 1), list(text = \"longitude\", relevance = 0.335207, count = 1)
```

basically I would like to extract just the string of text contain between \" and \"

and obtain something like this

```
1) "incredible hosts, Japan, support , result"
2) "British fleet, worst maritime disasters, British history, scilly Isles, sailors, evening, etc..."
```

Moreover I would like to create a data frame that helps le keep track of the relevance score contained in the text for each piece of text (considering that different raws might have different number of pieces of text) so to get something like this:

```
 col1                 col2.   col3.    col4.   col5.     col6.....  colA1    colA2.  .....
 incredible hosts     Japon  support  result    NA.      NA        0.87518.   0.675236....
 british fleet.       worst marit.......
```

basically a number of columns that is equal to the maximum number of pieces of text in a row, same for the columns corresponding to the score (each relevance score refers to a piece of text, so they re the same number).

If I can find a way to extract first the pieces of text and separate them by a comma, and then do the same with the relevance scores I think I can easily merge the two in a dataframe. so the problem is mainly extracting this 2 things from that text.

thank you in advance for your help,

Carlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings you show above are almost proper `R` code. So with minimal modification we can read the data into `R` directly:

```
txt1 <- 'list(text = \"incredible hosts\", relevance = 0.87518, count = 1), list(text = \"Japan\", relevance = 0.675236, count = 1), list(text = \"support\", relevance = 0.625663, count = 1), list(text = \"result\", relevance = 0.359757, count = 1)'
txt2 <- 'list(text = \"British fleet\", relevance = 0.912888, count = 1), list(text = \"worst maritime disasters\", relevance = 0.904047, count = 1), list(text = \"British history\", relevance = 0.755491, count = 1), list(text = \"Scilly Isles\", relevance = 0.716508, count = 1), list(text = \"sailors\", relevance = 0.691141, count = 1), list(text = \"evening\", relevance = 0.597375, count = 1), list(text = \"Tragedy\", relevance = 0.577141, count = 1), list(text = \"prize\", relevance = 0.565035, count = 1), list(text = \"rocks\", relevance = 0.543257, count = 1), list(text = \"innovation\", relevance = 0.529463, count = 1), list(text = \"longitude\", relevance = 0.335207, count = 1)'

txt1 <- gsub("text = ", "id = 1, text = ", txt1) # this is just if you want to have an ID later on
txt2 <- gsub("text = ", "id = 2, text = ", txt2)

list1 <- eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", txt1, ")")))
list2 <- eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", txt2, ")")))


df <- dplyr::bind_rows(list1, list2)
df
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>       id text                     relevance count
#>    <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1 incredible hosts             0.875     1
#>  2     1 Japan                        0.675     1
#>  3     1 support                      0.626     1
#>  4     1 result                       0.360     1
#>  5     2 British fleet                0.913     1
#>  6     2 worst maritime disasters     0.904     1
#>  7     2 British history              0.755     1
#>  8     2 Scilly Isles                 0.717     1
#>  9     2 sailors                      0.691     1
#> 10     2 evening                      0.597     1
#> 11     2 Tragedy                      0.577     1
#> 12     2 prize                        0.565     1
#> 13     2 rocks                        0.543     1
#> 14     2 innovation                   0.529     1
#> 15     2 longitude                    0.335     1
```

From here it's much easier to wrangle them into any form you might want.

## Update

After your comment I changed my answer to show how you can use this approach with a bigger dataset and get it into quanteda:

Let's say you read in your data and each text is a value in a vector now:

```
txt <- c('list(text = \"incredible hosts\", relevance = 0.87518, count = 1), list(text = \"Japan\", relevance = 0.675236, count = 1), list(text = \"support\", relevance = 0.625663, count = 1), list(text = \"result\", relevance = 0.359757, count = 1)',
         'list(text = \"British fleet\", relevance = 0.912888, count = 1), list(text = \"worst maritime disasters\", relevance = 0.904047, count = 1), list(text = \"British history\", relevance = 0.755491, count = 1), list(text = \"Scilly Isles\", relevance = 0.716508, count = 1), list(text = \"sailors\", relevance = 0.691141, count = 1), list(text = \"evening\", relevance = 0.597375, count = 1), list(text = \"Tragedy\", relevance = 0.577141, count = 1), list(text = \"prize\", relevance = 0.565035, count = 1), list(text = \"rocks\", relevance = 0.543257, count = 1), list(text = \"innovation\", relevance = 0.529463, count = 1), list(text = \"longitude\", relevance = 0.335207, count = 1)')
```

Instead of changing every object, you can just loop over every element:

```
txt <- lapply(seq_along(txt), function(i) { # this is just if you want to have an ID later on
  gsub("text = ", paste0("id = ", i, ", text = "), txt[i])
})

list <- lapply(txt, function(x) {
  dplyr::bind_rows(eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", x, ")"))))
})

df <- dplyr::bind_rows(list)
```

Once you have a `data.frame`, there is only a little bit of data wrangling left to do before you can work in quanteda:

```
library(dplyr)
df_wide <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste(text, collapse = " "), relevance = list(relevance))

library(quanteda)

corp <- corpus(df_wide, docid_field = "id", text_field = "text")
corp
#> Corpus consisting of 2 documents and 1 docvar.
corp$documents$relevance
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.875180 0.675236 0.625663 0.359757
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 0.912888 0.904047 0.755491 0.716508 0.691141 0.597375 0.577141
#>  [8] 0.565035 0.543257 0.529463 0.335207
```

Comment: thank you, I see how it works, however I need to apply this for the entire dataset, and I cannot repeat the process for each row as I have more than 1000. Furthermore I would need to keep the same format as above, Since I will need to input the resulting data frame in quanteda as a document feature matrix

Comment: I changed my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach which at least outputs all the matching quotes terms:

```
x <- "list(text = \"incredible hosts\", relevance = 0.87518, count = 1), list(text = \"Japan\", relevance = 0.675236, count = 1), list(text = \"support\", relevance = 0.625663, count = 1), list(text = \"result\", relevance = 0.359757, count = 1)"
m <- gregexpr("\"(.*?)\"", x)
regmatches(x, m)[[1]]

[1] "\"incredible hosts\"" "\"Japan\""            "\"support\""
[4] "\"result\""
```